# Can not find InternationalizationShoppingContextServlet.java

Tags: java, mobile, module, atg

In ATG Mobile-Server module `InternationalizationShoppingContextServlet.java` class is missing?

What is the impace of this class?

```
cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class InternationalizationShoppingContextServlet
```

Regds,
Sudhahar.S

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old question but answering none-the-less)

The class [InternationalizationShoppingContextServlet.java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/CRS.93/apidoc/atg/projects/store/servlet/pipeline/InternationalizationShoppingContextServlet.html) is part of the CustomerReferenceStore module. Make sure that CRS is installed and accessible to your build application, prior to building the Mobile Module.